# CSS overflow on sides from text on small columns

Tags: html, css

I have an own made grid system, the gutters for that i'm doing with `margin`s.

The HTML markup for that looks like this:

```
        <div class="row">
            <div class="column" data-size="1"></div>
            <div class="column" data-size="1"></div>
            <div class="column" data-size="1"></div>
            <div class="column" data-size="1"></div>
            <div class="column" data-size="1"></div>
            <div class="column" data-size="1"></div>
            <div class="column" data-size="1"></div>
            <div class="column" data-size="1"></div>
            <div class="column" data-size="1"></div>
            <div class="column" data-size="1"></div>
            <div class="column" data-size="1"></div>
            <div class="column" data-size="1"></div>
        </div>
```

The `data-size` attribute determinates what the column size should be, this goes from 1 through the maximum amount of columns in a row (Wich is 12 in my case, but i can change that).

Here are the CSS properties of the row:

```
.row {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-bottom: 1.95313%;
  *zoom: 1; }
  .row:before, .row:after {
    content: "";
    display: table; }
  .row:after {
    clear: both; }
```

And here from the `column`:

```
  .row > .column {
    min-height: 75px;
    background: #ddd;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -o-box-sizing: border-box;
    margin-left: 0.97656%;
    margin-right: 0.97656%; }
```

Whenever i put a `h1` or other headers in the smaller columns such as `data-size` 1 or 2, this happens:

[image]

New html markup:

```
        <div class="row">
            <div class="column" data-size="1"><h1>Header 1 Header 1 Header 1</h1></div>
            <div class="column" data-size="1"></div>
            <div class="column" data-size="1"></div>
            <div class="column" data-size="1"></div>
            <div class="column" data-size="1"></div>
            <div class="column" data-size="1"></div>
            <div class="column" data-size="1"></div>
            <div class="column" data-size="1"></div>
            <div class="column" data-size="1"></div>
            <div class="column" data-size="1"></div>
            <div class="column" data-size="1"></div>
            <div class="column" data-size="1"></div>
        </div>
```

As you can see, the `column`s width is still working fine. You can see that on the `background-color`.

I tried putting `overflow: hidden` on the `column`s CSS properties, but that just hide a part of the text.

How do i make it so that the text changes size so it fits in the column?

**This happens only on `header`s, on `paragraph`'s it doesnt overflow.**

[**Demo here**](http://jsfiddle.net/m32F5/)

Comment: "How do i make it so that the text changes size so it fits in the column?" **Use an appropriate font-size?**

Comment: you can't or.. try this? http://fittextjs.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to use [`word-wrap: break-word`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/word-wrap):

```
.row > .column {
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/m32F5/1/

See also:

- [Can I use - CSS3 word-break](http://caniuse.com/#feat=word-break)
- [Can I use - CSS Hyphenation](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-hyphens)

Comment: Thanks, is this a common used way or is it better to just lower the `font-size`? Accepting answer in 5 minutes btw.

Comment: @Bas - It is much better to use smaller font size and to use a design that doesn't place large things inside small things. But the user may increase the text size, and it would be nice if it didn't break.

Comment: Youre right, ill think i'll leave it without the `word-wrap: break-word` for now and let the user decreate the `font-size` if nessecary. But surely accepting your answer.